# Coffescript error comes up in console: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

working on a rails app and my coffeescript code is broken. The

```
$('.post-reply4').hide()
```

is working but nothing else is. Clicking on the message4 link doesn't do anything.

And the console gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

coffescript:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

jQuery ->

    toggleThis = () ->
        $('#post-reply4').show()

    $('.post-reply4').hide()

    $('#message4').on('click') ->
        toggleThis
```

html:

```
<a href="#message" id="message4">reply</a>

<div class="post-reply4">
stuff
</div>
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery

//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you post the generated javascript?

Comment: try to add parenthesis when you call toggleThis on the Click event of #message4: `$('#message4').on('click') -> toggleThis()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coffescript function declaration should be:

```
toggleThis = ->
    $('.post-reply4').show()
```

Then your call should be:

```
$('#message4').on 'click', (evt) ->
    toggleThis()
```

Please refer to this "[Little Book on CoffeeScript](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/02_syntax.html)" for syntax.

Update: Thanks to @muistooshort, who pointed in his comment below, you are using id selector '#post-reply4' when you should be using class selector '.post-reply4' as updated in the code above.

Comment: Hey thanks @vinodadhikary. But when I click on #message4, the post-reply4 doesn't show. This is what it compiles down into in js

(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    var toggleThis;
    $('.post-reply4').hide();
    toggleThis = function() {
      return $('#post-reply4').toggle();
    };
    return $('#message4').on('click', function(evt) {
      return toggleThis();
    });
  });

}).call(this);

Comment: Why `(evt) -> toggleThis()` when just `$(...).on 'click', toggleThis` would do?

Comment: @PavanKatepalli: You seem to have your class and id selectors a bit mixed up.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that!